# What is the chance of a meteor hitting my town?

Tags: terraria-mobile

So I want to break the hearts (with help from my cousin) but he says meteors can fall. What is the chance it will hit my town? (Town is Right next to my spawn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Meteorites](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meteorite_%28biome%29) can fall **nearly** anywhere on the map, however there are the following restrictions:

- The central 16% of the world around your initial spawn point is protected from falling meteors. Meteorites will not land within 25 tiles of a player, NPC or a chest.
- A meteor wont fall if there's already a large amount of un-mined meteorite in the world

Comment: A meteor just landed and hit the dungeon. I mined every bit of it for no real reason. Wow.

Answer (score 1):

Meteorite spawns can occur absolutely anywhere on the map, so there's always a chance it'll hit your town. It's not particularly likely (and indeed less likely on larger worlds) but it can happen.

You could always build a wall above your town to take the hit if you're still concerned about it.